# How to choose which table columns to show

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a table with columns (first name, last name, place of birth, date of birth and three more). 
Above the table I have a button which opens a modal with checkboxes with names of columns.

Here is code with checkboxes.

```
    <div *ngFor="let column of columns">
         <md-checkbox id="{{column.name}}"
                      [checked]="checked"
                      [(ngModel)]="setColumn"
                      (click)="showColumn($event, column.name)">{{ column.name }}</md-checkbox>
   </div>
```

So, when checkboxes for first name and last name are checked and when button save is clicked, table should show only columns first name and last name.

**Can someone give me advice how to do that?**

EDIT: 
Code for displaying table:

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <label>
                <a (click)="sortColumn('firstName')">
                    First Name<span>
                        <i *ngIf="order==1" class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                        <i *ngIf="order==(-1)" class="fa fa-caret-up"></i>
                    </span>
                </a>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <label>
                <a (click)="sortColumn('lastName')">
                    Last Name<span>
                        <i *ngIf="order==1" class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                        <i *ngIf="order==(-1)" class="fa fa-caret-up"></i>
                    </span>
                </a>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <label>
                <a (click)="sortColumn('placeOfBirth')">
                    Place of Birth<span>
                        <i *ngIf="order==1" class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                        <i *ngIf="order==(-1)" class="fa fa-caret-up"></i>
                    </span>
                </a>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <label>
                <a (click)="sortColumn('birthdate')">
                    BirthDate<span>
                        <i *ngIf="order==1" class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                        <i *ngIf="order==(-1)" class="fa fa-caret-up"></i>
                    </span>
                </a>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" *ngFor="let user of users | sortingTable:path:order | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 45, currentPage: p}">
        <div class="col">
            <label>{{ user.firstName }}</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <label>{{ user.lastName }}</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <label>{{ user.placeOfBirth }}</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <label>{{ user.birthdate }}</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that there are two components. ModelComponent.ts and Checkbox.component.ts

In the modal, write a 'change' function on checkbox. So the moment you check/uncheck, this event will get fire. save all the values corresponding to checked checkboxes in an array. For example if you check the 'firstName', 'lastName' then your array should contain these two values .
Now when you click on save button and pass this array as parameter to it.
Now you can use shared Service (used to communicate between two components). You can use BehaviourSubject and then subscribe to it in checkbox.component.ts file
Have a look at https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service
for communication between two components using service.

Comment: Thanks, but how I put array into Behavior subject?

Comment: You donot have to put array in behaviourSubject. Rather you will doing something like this in your modal.component.ts :    save (arr){
this.SharedService.callCheckboxFunc(arr);
}

Comment: and then in your sharedservice.ts file:  
export class SharedService {

  private callCheckbox= new Subject<any>();
  
  callCheckbox$ = this.callCheckbox.asObservable();


  callCheckboxFunc(arrayOfChkboxVal){
    this.callCheckbox.next(arrayOfChkboxVal);
  }

} And after this subscribe to it in checkbox.component.ts constructor like:  constructor(private sharedService: SharedService) {
    sharedService.callCheckbox$.subscribe(
      response => {
        console.log(response); // You will get your array values over here in response 
      });
  }

Comment: Thanks, did it and works. here comes the fun part with hiding columns :)

Comment: You might be displaying data in the table using *ngFor.. Iterating over an array right? Can you share that array, so it will be easy for me to tell you how to hide

Comment: Okay. Assuming your array received from modal and the array of table looks like below then:var arrayOfChkBox= ['firstName']; var finalArr = [] ;

this.array = [{firstName:"John", lastName:'abc', ......},{firstName:"Michael", lastName:'def',.....},{firstName:"Marry", lastName:'ghi',.....}]  

this.array.map(function(i){
arrayOfChkBox.map(function(o){
for (var e in i){
if(e==o){alert(e);console.log(i)
finalArr.push(i);console.log('arr',finalArr);
}
} 
});
}); this.array= finalArr; // this.array is array iterating over table

Comment: So what basically i did in above code is, based on the 'arrayOfChbox'  array which has only one element 'firstName', i am checking the main 'array' (table array ) values and showing only those objects which has firstName key in it. Hope this helps